# Print the rquest on Apache Camel asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders

Tags: java, apache-camel

I’m generating async request to endpoint using below Apache camel template producer

Please let me know how can I print/log below template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders()
send request(not the response)
Apache-camel version:2.10

```
template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders(endpoint, sendMessage, httpClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you think logging the arguments passed to the asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders method isn't good enough? I'd suggest to log the following way:

```
log.debug("generating async request {} to endpoint {}", sendMessage, endpoint);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. but actually i want to see all request

Comment: What do you mean by see all request?